# Basic fundamental of New Tabs

Tags: facebook, woothemes

How woobox and ShortStacks are managing multiple tabs on our single page ?
I mean, by using one facebook app we can have only one page tab. while ShortStack is able to install multiple tabs on same page. So, can anyone explain me, how they are doing ??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> by using **one** facebook app we can have only **one** page tab

Correct. And with **multiple** facebook apps , you can have **multiple** tabs - under the SAME page.

See, dont get confused, you can give the same page url same for all of your apps.

Comment: Thank you for your  quick response. Can you tell me how we can show different content on tab as per page ?

Comment: different content, as in ? each tab is a different app only.

Comment: I mean, I can use same app for 3 different pages. and for all 3 pages, can I view different content ?

Comment: That's what i am asking, what different content? If you are using the same app for your different pages, the content of that app would be same only?

Comment: suppose, I have 2 page, one for Sports and another is for Music. I've installed same app on both page. now, on both tab I want to show specific content.

Comment: I'm not sure but I guess you cant do that since header info for both would be the same (am not sure), since its unnecessary, i'll prefer making two different apps for this.

Comment: Ok. I'll figure out what is possible.. Thank you for your help, I'll ask you again if I've any other queries.